# Print numbers with a percentage sign

Tags: python, formatting, xlsxwriter

I tried to use one `%`, and double `%%`, both seem to multiply my number to 100 times bigger.

This is what it looks like:

> percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})

result: `9403.00%`

> percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%%'})

result: `9403.00%%`

> percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})

result: `94.03`, which is what I want, I just need to append a `%` on the end.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If the value is `94.03` then simply *formatting* it as a percent will (correctly) yield `9403.00%`.  This is because `1 == 100%`.

Comment: @pnuts   has it, you need a custom string format, not a number format, to simply *append* the `%` to the way the value *appears*.  This will not in any way alter the underlying datta, it's just a mask that changes the way the cell *looks*, visually.

Comment: Thank you!! pnuts, 0.00"%"' works, you saved my day!

Comment: haha, I was asked to put a tag, I guess I clicked the wrong one. sorry. let me see if I can change it.

Answer (score 9):

[The Format Class](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/format.html#format) has a lot of detail about formatting with **XlsxWriter**. Around halfway there is a section on *format.set_num_format()* though this does not specifically mention formatting for percentage sign. It can be achieved so:

```
percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00"%"'})
```

This merely appends `%` (say `9` to `9%`) without any conversion from say `9` to `900%`.

Comment: New link to docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html?highlight=format